# MATLAB GUI Button with Keyboard Control

Tags: matlab

I have a button in a GUI. which the user presses to execute a Callback. But, I would like the user to be able to press the up arrow key instead of clicking to execute the callback.

EDIT: I am using GUIDE to make the GUI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this thread:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/12034

Just slightly modifying the code from there to here (put the following in a file called `testGUI.m`

```
function testGUI
g = figure('KeyPressFcn', @keyPress)
MyButton = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton','Callback',@task);

    function task(src, e)
        disp('button press');
    end

    function keyPress(src, e)
        switch e.Key
            case 'uparrow'
                task(MyButton, []);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: But how do I define the up arrow key?

Comment: I edited my response so that it would do the callback on 'uparrow' instead of on 'c'. If you want to know what 'e.Key' is for any key on your keyboard, just put a breakpoint at line 'switch e.Key' and then run the code, press the key you want to use and then check what 'e.Key' is for the key that you pressed.